# Can't pull a docker image using ansible and community.general.docker_image

Tags: docker, ansible

In a ansible playbook, I'm trying to pull an image, and retag it:

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:amd64-1.4.4
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:amd64-1.4.4 hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:latest
```

I can't even succeed to pull it.

I do it with `community.general.docker_image`:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
```

and then my playbook:

```
---
- name: Pull an image
  hosts: nodes
  become: true
  community.general.docker_image:
    name: hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:amd64-1.4.4
    source: pull
```

And running with :

```
ansible-playbook install-dependencies.yml
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR! 'community.general.docker_image' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in 'install-dependencies.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Pull an image
  ^ here
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: which version of ansible are you using? `ansible --version`

Comment: ansible 2.10.4,  python version = 3.8.5

Comment: ah sure , sorry didn't notice, you're missing the tasks option in your playbook

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the tasks option in your playbook:

---

```
- name: Pull an image
  hosts: nodes
  become: true
  tasks:
  - community.general.docker_image:
    name: hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:amd64-1.4.4
    source: pull
```

Comment: I copy and pasted this exact code and got the following error. Do you know what the issue might be for me? 

ERROR! conflicting action statements: community.general.docker_image, source

Comment: Just missing some indentation under the module name, i.e. `name` and `source` need to be indented to the right